# Read user's Google Fit activities through REST calls

Tags: rest, google-api, google-fit

I have seen that a Fitness History API already exists for android but i can't find anything similar for REST services. All i want to do is get the fitness activities of an authorized user's account. For example, i would like to get all the "walking" activities that he did in a specific day or period. Is there a simple way of doing this from a web app, since the documentation can be confusing?

Comment: have you found any solution for activity rest api?

Answer (score 3):

Fit has a [full REST API available](https://developers.google.com/fit/rest/v1/get-started). To get activities (called sessions in the API) you'll want to use the [Users.sessions.list](https://developers.google.com/fit/rest/v1/reference/users/sessions/list) method. It supports `startTime` and `endTime` parameters to timebox results and once you have the results you can filter them based on [activityType](https://developers.google.com/fit/rest/v1/reference/activity-types). In this case `activityType` for walking is `7` but also potentially `93`, `94`, and `95` for more specific types of walking.

If you get an `access_token` authorized with the scope of `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/fitness.activity.read` you can get a list of sessions for the current user as simple as:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/fitness/v1/users/me/sessions?access_token=xyz123
```

Comment: Hello, 
First of all thanks for your time and sorry for that late answer. The method you described seems fine for activities entered manually through the web browser but i cannot fetch the activities monitored by the device. If you have google-fit on your smartphone it will constantly monitor your walking, but this data isn't available through sessions. Is there anything i'm missing?

P.S. i have tried to go through dataSources to get some info but i found it extremely confusing

Comment: @abraham. We can get all activity list here. Where we can find steps count for that activity. I mean individual?

Comment: @Envy Same experience here. Were you ever able to figure out how to get the activities automatically entered via smart devices?

Comment: @theblang Facing the same issue right now. Manually entered activities show up in sessions.list results but automatically tracked ones do not.